# Dataset help for TF-IDF and Vector Model

Tags: dataset, corpus, tf-idf, cosine-similarity

I want to compare TF-IDF, Vector model and some optimization of TF-IDF algorithm.
For that I need a dataset (at least 100 documents of English text). I am not able to find one. any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends the application that you use TF-IDF. for example if you want to find keywords you could use "Mendely" dataset or for tagging using "Delicious" data.